# Background image does not stretch to bottom of page: cannot use background-attachment

Tags: html, ios, css, background, position

I'm working on a project with a background-image that needs to fully cover the entire page. I am unable to use the property "background-attachment: cover" because this page also needs to be viewable on iOS, which does not support background-attachment.

```css
.sky-background {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514477917009-389c76a86b68?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* cannot use this property */
  /* background-attachment:fixed; */
}
```

```html
<body class="sky-background">
</body>
```

I've been looking for alternatives to use for iOS, but I haven't found anything satisfactory so far. Can anyone offer any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body.sky-background {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the document height. Try `body {min-height: 100vh;}` or better `html {100%};`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, hopefully It will help you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
 html {
  height: 100%;
 }
 body {
   background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514477917009-389c76a86b68?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80");
   background-position: center;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-color: #cccccc;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>The background-image Property</h1>
 <p>Hello World!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only adding height on your body element will do the work. Use height: 100vh; on .sky-background. Hope that'd help

```css
.sky-background {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514477917009-389c76a86b68?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body class="sky-background">
</body>
</html>
```